# Python range with fixed number of elements and fixed interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I need to create a `range` like this in Pyhton:

```
1 ... 4 ... 7 ... 10 ... 13 ... 16 ...
```

But I would like to estabilish not *the end of range*, but the *number of elements*.

For example:

```
range_num_of_elements(1, num_of_elements=4, interval=3)
```

Gives as result:

```
[1, 4, 7, 10]
```

How can I do it?

EDIT: this question

[Creating a range with fixed number of elements (length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043915/creating-a-range-with-fixed-number-of-elements-length)

Doesn't answers my question. I wanna specify *start, interval, num*, where the question above specifies *start, end, num*.

Comment: `[3*n+1 for n in range(4)]`

Comment: You want `range(start, start + num_of_elements * interval, interval)`.  That will return a range object (in Python 3).  If you want an actual list, just pass it to `list()`.  The solutions that resort to a comprehension to obtain the result are doing unnecessary work.

Comment: you can easily do it with the built-in function `range`: `list(range(start, num_elements*interval, interval))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could define your range just like this:

```
def my_range(start, num_elements, step):
    return range(start, start+step*num_elements, step)

list(my_range(1, 4, 3))
# [1, 4, 7, 10]
```

this would have all the nice features of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range); e.g.:

```
7 in my_range(1, 4, 3)  # True
8 in my_range(1, 4, 3)  # False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[start + interval * n for n in range(num_of_elements)]
```

Where

```
start = 1
interval = 3
num_of_elements = 4
```

This will give

```
[1, 4, 7, 10]
```

Or you can just compute the appropriate arguments to `range`, as Tom Karzes suggested in the comments:

```
range(start, start + interval * num_of_elements, interval)
```